# Bottom Bar как поставить цвета для вкладок

Tags: java, android, tab

[репозиторий](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar)

Нужно поставить разные цвета для каждой вкладки, в репозитории показано как сделать если их больше 3, а у меня именно 3, помогите реализовать.Или если не возвожможно с этим репо то посоветуйте другой,спасибо.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
BottomBar bottomBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
    bottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.bottom_bar_menu, new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {
            if (menuItemId == R.id.bb_menu_recents) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuTabReSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {
            if (menuItemId == R.id.bb_menu_recents) {

            }
        }
    });

}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    bottomBar.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

}

нужно как тут:

[image: как тут]

Comment: а какая принципиальная разница, больше трех этих вкладок или ровно три, что вы не можете решить эту проблему?

Comment: @pavlofff когда их 3 или меньше, цвета начинают игнорироватся и заливается фон белым цветом, как по ссылке в репозитории, первая гифке.

Answer (score 1):

По вашей же ссылке есть вот такие строки:

```
// Set the color for the active tab. Ignored on mobile when there are more than three tabs.
mBottomBar.setActiveTabColor("#009688");
```

Comment: Это меняет цвет иконки активной вкладки.

Comment: @newakkoff, попробуйте ещё вот эти методы `setMaxFixedTabs`, `useFixedMode`

Comment: к сожалению тоже не то)

Comment: @newakkoff, ну, покапайте сами тогда исходники либы. Я там больше ничего не нашёл.